# Django 1.9 with Python 3.4 with MySQL support (Fedora)

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

The question is so simple:

How can I used MySQL database with Django 1.9 + Python 3.4 in Fedora? I'm actually using a `virtualenv` if that adds more info.

I tried installing `mysqlclient` but that didn't work. And I really don't know how to go about the `MySQL connector Python` described here: [MySQL DB API Drivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

When I try to install `mysqlclient` with `pip` it fails with: `OSError: mysql_config not found`.

Comment: "I tried installing mysqlclient but that didn't work." - What was the problem? With just "didn't work" we have no idea what might be wrong. Also, _how_ did you install `mysqlclient`?

Comment: @marcelm I'm sorry, I was frustrated and tired. I did edit my question so you can see what error installing `mysqlclient` produces when I try to install via `pip`: `pip install mysqlclient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python2

Try this steps:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
# Create your username and password in MySQL
# Create your db in MySQL
yum install MySQL-python
```

For python2 or python3:

```
pip install mysqlclient
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev

In settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': YOUR DB NAME,
        'USER': YOUR USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': YOUR PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 80,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it fails with a `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. I think `MySQL-python` only support Python 2.x

Comment: Sorry I forgot, try this

pip install mysqlclient;
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: That's right, thank you! can you add to your answer, just for the sake of completeness: `sudo dnf install python-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS` for people who see this and come looking something for Fedora/Red Hat/CentOS. I'll accept your answer! :-)

Comment: It's now complete, sure! :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) says:

**Prerequisites:** 
You may need to install the Python and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

```
sudo dnf install python-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
```

And after that, install normally from **pip**:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

The initial problem was that I didn't have `mysql-devel` installed. That's why pip installation failed.