# Python 3 Django - replace SQLite with MySQL (Linux Fedora)

Tags: mysql, linux, django, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3, Django (1.11), on Linux fedora (23), (which use mariadb) and I'm trying to make it work with MySQL - instead of SQLite. And after about 8 hours of searching everything on google, I really doesn't know what to do..

I found a couple of times something with "python-mysql-connector" (something like this) but It's not really work.. (the installation)

I think that the main problem is that Django, is working with Python 3. However, Python 3 doesn't have "MySQLdb" library, (which Django trying to import) so if I edits this in the config file (of django)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

to this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/my.cnf', # i don't know if really necessary (mysql settings.. I think..)
        },
    }
}
```

so I get this error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

(and of course more lines, but they doesn't important)

and

pip3 install mysqlclient

(which I found here [Django 1.9 with Python 3.4 with MySQL support (Fedora)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583257/django-1-9-with-python-3-4-with-mysql-support-fedora) )

print this

```
[noam@localhost-localdomain ~]$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-18mq5vpo/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-18mq5vpo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-18mq5vpo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-18mq5vpo/mysqlclient/
[noam@localhost-localdomain ~]$
```

So how can I make it work? I'm really need that, and have no idea what to do..
I'll be glad for any help :)

Thanks, Noam

Comment: Can you please share the contents of your `.cnf` file (without actual passwords).

Comment: it's just thit - http://pastebin.com/iMQ9S0tG (the default)

(and also if I'm writing in the Django settings - "user": "root", "pass": "" , so it still do nothing)

Comment: Try installing with yum mysql-devel mysql-lib prior to installing mysqlclient.

Comment: now pip (mysqlclient) print this - http://pastebin.com/utT49Shm
###
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
###
and mysql-devel worked, and mysql-lib not found